# SDWebImage Image received size is NULL

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdwebimage

I am trying to show progress view with SDWebImage but when i try below code then it return "0" in "receivedSize"

```
[cell. ImageHotDish setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:picName]
     placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:nil]
     options:0 progress:^(NSUInteger receivedSize, long long expectedSize) {
         NSLog(@"Downloaded = %@",receivedSize);
     } completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {
         [cell.ImageHotDish setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:picName]];
     }];
```

I am getting null velue in "receivedSize"

Can any one tell me where i am doing wrong

I have already check this solution but its not showing progress but just an activity indicator. What i am trying to get how much image have been downloaded.

[Show activity indicator in SDWebImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11262204/show-activity-indicator-in-sdwebimage)

Comment: is your image loaded?

Comment: @manujmv Yes image loaded successfully

Comment: is recievedSize always showing 0?

Comment: @manujmv Yes, Always getting size 0

Comment: why you are setting image again in the completion block?

Comment: @manujmv i just remove that. But the issue is not in completion box.

Comment: your code looks fine.it may be the particular file's behaviour.

Comment: @manujmv I try to trace out all file's behavior with breakpoint but same issue. Well thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: just put a placeholder image instead [UIImage imageNamed:nil] and try

Comment: @manujmv placeholder image is working fine. But i am trying to show progress with them how much new image have been loaded