# How progress bar shows on images while uploading and downloading like whats app

Tags: ios, image, chat, grand-central-dispatch

Hi I am working with Chat app every thing is working fine. Now facing one issue if i send one image to other user how to show progress indicator. In my code what i have done is
1) pick one image from galary.
2) upload to server from their i will get Image Url.
3) That url I am assigning to chat screen.

like below uploading image

```
-(void)uploadImage
{
//    dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("My Queue",NULL);
//    dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{

imageView.image = [mediaInfo objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
self.indicatorImage=[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
[self.indicatorImage setColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
//    [self.indicatorImage startAnimating];
self.indicatorImage.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(msgCell.mediaImageView.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(msgCell.mediaImageView.bounds));
[msgCell.mediaImageView addSubview:self.indicatorImage];
 [self.indicatorImage startAnimating];
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.0.24/openfire/index.php?"] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
// create request
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[theRequest setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
[theRequest setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
[theRequest setTimeoutInterval:30];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[theRequest addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
NSString *test = @"upload_image"; //Image name if you want a custom name
NSMutableData *body=[[NSMutableData alloc] init];
// add image data
imageData= UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image, 1.0);
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
if (imageData)
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", @"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\"; filename=\"",test,@".jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
if (imageData)
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[theRequest setHTTPBody:body];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[body length]];
[theRequest setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
// set URL
[theRequest setURL:url];
NSURLResponse *responceData;
returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:&responceData error:nil];
NSError *serializeError = nil;
NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization
                          JSONObjectWithData:returnData
                          options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                          error:&serializeError];
NSLog(@"print response after image post : %@",jsonData);
imgURL=[jsonData objectForKey:@"download"];
_data = [imgURL dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

//    });
```

}

after that i will get the image url Now I am assigning that to my chat screen method like below . I am using SDwebImage Library

```
 __weak typeof(self)weakSelf = self;
   [msgCell.mediaImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL         URLWithString:urlString] placeholderImage:nil options:SDWebImageCacheMemoryOnly | SDWebImageRefreshCached progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize) {
   [msgCell.mediaImageView updateImageDownloadProgress:(CGFloat)receivedSize/expectedSize];
           } completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
               [msgCell.mediaImageView reveal];
           }];
```

It is working fine image is added to chat screen but while uploading to server and downloading from server ineed to perform some animation like whatapp please any body knows how to do it please help me

Comment: Aren't you using a background thread for the upload part?

Comment: please see updated one

Comment: you have any code for showing animation like whatsApp?

Comment: @ruchiraRandana yes i tried like that also but when i use dispatch then first time it is not showing image.

Comment: @Birendra no i don't have

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433956/showing-accurate-progress-in-uiprogressview-while-downloading-images-in-iphone

Comment: you have to display like same whatsApp ?

Comment: you can use  MBProgressHUD to show progressbar

Comment: yes need to display like whatapp but MBProgressHUD not effective i tried with it. if you have any other approach please help me

Comment: i just tried to add activity indicator on Tableviewcell Imageview it worked showing loader , y it is not showing from ur side ?

Comment: @sanjuju are you using SDWebimage? and  gcd?. For me it is like  After loading only image is added to cell. but i need like while loading

Comment: @Bittoo  https://stackoverflow.com/q/46047271/2910061 can you please check and help to find better way?